# Add Dynamic CheckBox Handle CheckedChanged Event ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know why the event is not firing & how to find which checkbox control fired the event.

```
chkList1 = new CheckBox();
                            chkList1.Text = row["subj_nme"].ToString();
                            chkList1.ID = row["subjid"].ToString();
                            chkList1.Checked = true;
                            chkList1.Font.Name = "Verdana";
                            chkList1.Font.Size = 12;
                            chkList1.AutoPostBack = true;
                            chkList1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);
                            Panel1.Controls.Add(chkList1);

protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Called";
            }
```

Comment: Where do you create the Checkbox dynamically? Do you recreate it also on postbacks in page_load at the latest with the same ID as before?

Comment: The `object sender` is the check box that triggered the event when you clicked on it. Just cast it to `CheckBox`.

Comment: i m creating Checkbox on page_load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the events aren't firing, it's likely for one of two reasons:

1. The controls are recreated too late in the page lifecycle. Try creating the controls  during `OnInit`.
2. Validation is preventing the postback. To work around this you can set `CausesValidation` to false on all of the CheckBox controls.

You can find out which control triggered the event using the `sender` argument.

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //write the client id of the control that triggered the event
    Response.Write(((CheckBox)sender).ClientID);
}
```