# the checked change event of dynamically created checkbox is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

```
protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_TB.Text);

        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = dt.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            newcheck.AutoPostBack = true;
            newcheck.CausesValidation = false;
            newcheck.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(newcheck_CheckedChanged);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }

        con.Close();
    }

   protected void Done_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string labelId = "Label" + i.ToString();
            Label NewLabel = (Label)this.Labeldiv.FindControl(labelId);
            string checkBoxId = "Checkbox" + i.ToString();
            CheckBox newcheck = (CheckBox)this.Labeldiv.FindControl(checkBoxId);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDay", NewLabel.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventStatus", newcheck.Checked ? "true" : "false");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I have created the Labels & checkboxes dynamically in EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged......

I want to store them after checked the checkbox.....

but the CheckedChange Event is not fired.........??????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create checkboxlist dynamically and insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976836/create-checkboxlist-dynamically-and-insert-into-database)

Answer (score 0):

```
  newcheck .AutoPostBack = true;
  newcheck .CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);
```

This is the way to add event handler

change this line in your code:

```
 newcheck.CheckedChanged += newcheck_CheckedChanged;
```

Comment: add causes validation=false or create the controls durring pageload in if(!IsPostback)

Comment: I add CausesValidation=False; but also it not working..... how to put that code in PageLoad()??

Comment: just do all the code in the method  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
then add the control to panel only at the required time..!!

Comment: I write the code which is present in checkedchange in another method and call that in Page_Load and checkedchange event....

Comment: let me know your result after that..!! i think it would work..!! You tell me if it don't..!!

Comment: It gives Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at  string extractInteger = Regex.Match(currentCheckbox.ID, @"\d+").Value; in new method.

Comment: don't do that in EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: remove this code   CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            newcheck.AutoPostBack = true;
            newcheck.CausesValidation = false;
            newcheck.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(newcheck_CheckedChanged) 


from  EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: when I removed that code then how can create the Checkboxes after DDL SelectedIndex changed only???

Comment: you have already created the check box in pageLoad..!! you will show it in panel with this code: this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);

Comment: the checkboxes must create based on the ddl selection.... If we select 6 then 6 checkboxes must create, after that when we check the checkbox then the values must store into the sql-server.... but, you just create checkboxes add that to Labeldiv in Page_Load(), then when we select option from DDL, how it shows the checkboxes.....????

Comment: i think u must check this answer..!! i think that will solve your problem [link]('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473245/add-dynamic-checkbox-handle-checkedchanged-event-asp-net')

Comment: He create the CheckBoxes dynamically in Page_load, so He may get solution, but My senario is different, isn't it???

Comment: did you put a break point in the event and checked..?? let me know the result

Comment: It did nothing.... I put alert message also, but whats the use It did not fired...

Comment: ok, leave this.... I have already created CheckBoxes & Labels dynamically in DDL selectedIndexChanged, then now I want to Extract them into a Button Click Event to store them into sql-server........... How can I extract them into the Button Click event????

Comment: you want checkbox values right?? what is there so much to answer ?? just check whether check box is checked or not and store the corresponding value

Comment: It shows error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at the line 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDay", NewLabel.Text);'

Answer (score 0):

Adding checkbox in SelectedIndexChanged is not good way particularly when you need to bind an server event. Because these will not be available at the time of "LoadViewState" of page.

The best way is,

Add the checkbox & Labels in aspx page itself then set the `Visible="false"` and bind required events.

Then you can simply change its visibility in SelectedIndexCHange event by setting `newCheck.Visible = true`

By this way event will fire

Comment: If the DDL has 100 options, then its very difficult to the programmer.., Thats why I prefered to dynamic creation....

Comment: then you can use CheckBoxList control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList(v=vs.110).aspx

SelectIndexChange create List with required data to bind. then bind that as DataSource to CheckBoxList control.

Comment: CheckBoxList have SelectedIndexChanged instead of checkedchange

Comment: The reason why your code is not working is, all asp control event will fire after Page_Load. So at the time of page_load, the dynamically created controls from SelectIndexChanged won't have the chance to be there at Page_Load. Since its creation in event method.